# get activity instance from intent and finish it?

Tags: android

i have an activity

```
ActivityA
```

and I have another activity called:

```
ActivityB
```

I start the ActivityB in this ActivityA:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
```

now ActivityB is being displayed

in some situation i want finish ActivityB from ActivityA programmatically and **Question** is: how do it?

Comment: You can use Local broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial code is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
```

Now when `Activity A` is open, if you want to close `Activity B` do this from inside `Activity A`:

`finishActivity (CODE);`

Be aware that if `CODE` was used in other activities, it will close them all. For instance if you used `CODE` to open `Activity A`, it will close it too.

[Read this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity(int))